# Python library/code to parse .nt files from dbpedia

Tags: python, rdf, dbpedia

I want to parse the [dbpedia data](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads37) which is present in .nt format(N-Tuples). I have downloaded the .nt file and is there in my local disk.

For example, I want to find out all entities and their homepages.

I want to do it python. Right now the only way I could do is to do a grep, or iterate over all lines and select the ones which I want. Are there any good libraries which will allow me to do this?

I looked at [RDFLib](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/). But all the examples tell you how to write or create .nt format and not read from them.

Comment: What are entities and hompages in this file? Please add example data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [rdflib docs.](http://code.alcidesfonseca.com/docs/rdflib/gettingstarted.html):

```
>>> from rdflib.graph import Graph
>>> g = Graph()
>>> g.parse("demo.nt", format="nt")
```

your just needed the  `format=` kwarg.